# get the datasource name for doc from a view panel control in xpages

Tags: xpages

There is a `viewPanel1` that lists some docs. and having also the `var` property set to `rowData`.

How can I easily get the datasource name for a clickable doc / row ? Is there a 'quick' method something like:

`rowData.getDocument()./* getting the datasource name */` ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not get the data source name for the document but rather the form name. Based on the form name you can then decide on an action for that particular document.

Use the following:

```
rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form")
```

Comment: Thanks for your information. BTW, by your line of code, it must be a field named Form ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. There's always a field named form.

Comment: I suppose then it ( the Form field ) should have a default value / formula?

Comment: No need to as the form field is automatically set to the name of the form used to create the document.

Comment: So, I just created an editBox to my XPage name it -> Form. Then I added some code just for testing ( in the onClick event of the column ) : var formName = rowData.getDocument().getItemValueString("Form");

if ( formName == "fmCompanie")

{ getComponent('exampleDialog').show() } // my view panel lists some docs from 2 different Forms. and it seems it works. Hope my test code is a correct one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome. Remember to accept this and your other questions with valid answers as accepted (in order to be a good Stack Exchange citizen).

Comment: Yep, of course. I always accept those answers that helped me to resolve my issue(s). : )